# How can i create web services using MySql Stored procedures in strongloop

Tags: mysql, rest, stored-procedures, strongloop

I'm new to concept of strong loop & want to create web services using MySql stored procedures instead of table schema, but i'm not getting any related samples or step by step documentation for how & where to define input & output parameters, How to define getters & setters, How can i Use stored procedure(i do in java). so can anybuddy help me for that. I'm trying following code in "Mode.js". where do i need to make changes

```
     module.exports = function(StaticData) {


    StaticDataremoteMethod(
   var ds = server.dataSources.MySQL;
var sql = 'SELECT * FROM static_data';
ds.connector.execute(sql, function(err, data)
  {
    if(err) return err;
    console.log(err);
    });,
    {
        accepts: [
        {arg: 'id', type: 'number', required: true}
      ],
       http: {path: '/:id/StaticDataremoteMethod', verb: 'get'}
    }
  );

};
```

for same I'm getting following exception on command prompt

> C:\Users\anupd\Desktop\ToursDemo>slc arc
>   Swagger: skipping unknown type "subscription".
>   Swagger: skipping unknown type "subscription".
>   Loading workspace C:\Users\anupd\Desktop\ToursDemo
>   StrongLoop Arc is running here: http://localhost:65058/#/
>   C:\Users\anupd\Desktop\ToursDemo\common\models\static-data.js:5
>      var ds = server.dataSources.MySQL;
>      ^^^
>
> SyntaxError: Unexpected token var
>       at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:53:16)
>       at Module._compile (module.js:374:25)
>       at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:417:10)
>       at Module.load (module.js:344:32)
>       at Function.Module._load (module.js:301:12)
>       at Module.require (module.js:354:17)
>       at require (internal/module.js:12:17)
>       at C:\Users\anupd\Desktop\ToursDemo\node_modules\loopback-boot\lib\executor.
>   js:226:20
>       at Array.forEach (native)
>       at defineModels (C:\Users\anupd\Desktop\ToursDemo\node_modules\loopback-boot
>   \lib\executor.js:207:23)

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why Off-Topic?? It's related with tag provided by stack overflow. could you plz explain??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Refer this link.

dataSource.connector.execute(sql, params, cb); 
or 
dataSource.connector.query(sql, params, cb);

https://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/Database+connectors
https://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/Executing+native+SQL

```
  method()
{

var server = require('../server');
var ds = server.dataSources.MySQL;
var sql = 'select * from Appuser';
ds.connector.execute(sql, function(err, data)
  {
    if(err) return err;
    console.log(err);
    console.log("data",data);
  });
}
```

Comment: @ Riaz, Thank you for your valuable suggestion, but I'm not able to write code with the help of those links, if possible, can you provide me any sample snippet?, That will be an great help

Comment: @AnupDeshpande, I haven't done this before, I will try ok.

Comment: I just tried with saw sql, its working. you try with stored procedure it should work . note: param is optional parameter, it can used to pass value.

Comment: Do i need to add such code in "Model.json" file's method section or any other file.

Comment: In model.js  refer this https://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/Remote+methods  https://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/Getting+started+with+LoopBack  https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-getting-started

Comment: can you plz help me with updated question?? or explain step by step evolution in simple step by step manner

Answer (score 1):

Just create model like DemoModel.js and copy and paste  below code inside DemoModel.js

```
   module.exports = function(DemoModel) {
    var server = require('../../server/server');
      var ds = server.dataSources.MySQL;

    DemoModel.list = function(optionalparam, cb) {  


      var sql = 'select * from DemoModel';
      ds.connector.execute(sql, function(err, data)
      {
      if(err) return err;
      console.log(err);
      console.log("data",data);
        cb(null, data);
      });

    }

    DemoModel.remoteMethod(
        'list', 
        {
          accepts: {arg: 'param', type: 'string'},
          returns: {arg: 'result', type: 'object'},
          http: {path: '/list', verb: 'get'}
        }
    );


    };
```

> just call like : http://localhost:3000/api//DemoModels/list
>   and also look this  http://localhost:3000/explorer/